# Finding the length of a helix

Tags: problem-solving, pi, arc-length

Does anyone have any clue on how to start this question off?

> The highly scary helter skelter at the fair is a cylindrical tower of height 30 metres and circumference 8 metres. The slide is wound around the tower exactly 5 times. What’s the total length of the slide?

I think it's to do with Helixes or something and we have not covered any of that in class. I've thought about 'unravelling it' as in making it a rectangle with the width being 30 and the length being 8π but do not know what to do next!
Any help is much appreciated as I have no clue on what to do!!

Comment: This question is part of the [Newcastle University Senior Challenge '17](http://www.ncl.ac.uk/maths/outreach/teachers/challenge/) (question 3 _Highly Scary Helter Skelter_ of [this pdf](http://www.ncl.ac.uk/media/wwwnclacuk/mathematicsandstatistics/files/mathschallenge2017/Newcastle%20Senior%20Maths%20Challenge%202017.pdf)). The stated due date for entries is 10 March 2017, and this question will remain locked with answers temporarily deleted until after this date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a single winding the height would be $6$ metres.

The circumference of the cylinder is given as $8$ so no $\pi$ required.

Unfold the cylinder and the single winding unravels as a straight line corresponding to the diagonal of a right-angle triangle of side lengths $6,8$.

By Pythagoras' theorem, the length of the diagonal is $\cdots\bullet $.

Total spiral length is $5$ times this, which is $\cdots\bullet $. [image][image][image]

Comment: By Pythagoras' Theorem would it be 10?
Therefore: 5*10= 50??

Comment: Yes, and so ...

Comment: Ermm, the slide is also 50..?

Comment: how does 5*10=30?

Comment: I fixed it. It was a typo sorry ;-;.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Take a piece of A4 paper, draw a diagonal across it, and roll it up into a cylinder. That might be a good illustration. :)

Comment: Thank you very much! This question was bugging me for days!! :)

Comment: You're welcome! Glad you found it helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

If you know a bit of calculus then you could parameterize the helix as
$$
x(t) = \frac{4}{\pi}\cos(10\pi t), \quad y(t) = \frac{4}{\pi}\sin(10\pi t), \quad z(t) = 30 t, \quad t \in [0,1]
$$
The arc length is then
\begin{align}
A &= \int_0^1 \sqrt{(x'(t))^2 + (y'(t))^2 + (z'(t))^2}\,dt\\
&= \int_0^1 \sqrt{1600 + 900}\,dt\\
&= 50
\end{align}

Comment: I have no clue! But thanks for your input!