# Wrapping a column with lights

Tags: calculus, measure-theory

I would like to spiral wrap the columns in front of my home with Christmas lights. The answer I'm looking for is:  If know the height of the column, the circumference and the length of the light string, how far apart do I space the spiral?
column height:  90"
column circumference: 54"
length of lights:  56'  (or 672")

I plan on installing wire hooks at these intervals on the back of the column.
Let me know if I'm missing some information.
THANKS!

Comment: You need to know how to compute the length of a helix (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2160851) or (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2307561)

Answer (score 2):

If you imagine your ideal spiral, and "unroll" your column like a paper towel, then your lights will be the hypotenuse of a right triangle.

Imagine a right triangle with a hypotenuse of length $672$ and one leg of length $90$. The other leg will have length $\sqrt{672^2 - 90^2} \approx 666$. This is how much length you have to wrap around the circumference: you can wrap around $\approx \frac{666}{54}\approx 12.3$ "laps".

Thus, during each "lap" the lights go upward $\approx \frac{90}{12.3} \approx 7.3$ inches.

Comment: Makes perfect sense and that explanation took me back to my highschool classes before computers, heck, before the abacus. :)  Thanks for the quick response!!